# C++ ofstream equivalent to Win32 CreateFile with CREATE_NEW

Tags: c++, file, file-io, io, fstream

In an application I want to be sure that I am writing a brand new (binary) file. In Win32 programming I know I can do this with [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) using `CREATE_NEW`, but I can't work out a pure C++ standard way.

> Creates a new file, only if it does not already exist.
>   If the specified file exists, the function fails and the last-error code is set to ERROR_FILE_EXISTS (80).
>   If the specified file does not exist and is a valid path to a writable location, a new file is created.

I tried using `std::ios::out | std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate` then seeing if `tellp` gave me the start of the file or not, but apart from the obvious case that this would still overwrite an empty file, it also seems to truncate a non-empty file anyway as if I used `std::ios::trunc`...

This was on VS2013, although I assume this is not a compiler/library bug.

Comment: iostream users have muddled through this for the past 16 years, probably by first trying to open the file to check if it already exists.  Closest you could get with the CRT is _open() with the _O_CREAT and _O_EXCL mode flags.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ standard doesn't have an API guaranteeing a new file. When opening an existing file in write-only mode without specifying `std::ios_base::app` it is truncated (independent on whether `std::ios_base::trunc` is used). I don't know about Windows but on POSIX this would retain the original inode and processes already having opened the file can still access it.

If it is sufficient to get an open and empty file rather than a new one, omiting `std::ios_base::in` and `std::ios_base::app` should do the trick (note that opening an `std::fstream` or an `std::ifstream` implicitly adds `std::ios_base::in`).